# Azure PS command returns empty list

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-aks, azure-cli, azure-resource-group, azure-cloud-shell

We have created a resource group with a VMSS instance within.

When running the "az vmss list" command within the Cloud Shell, we are able to get the respective resource.

[image: CloudShell CLI Command output]

However, when running the exact same command in PS, it returns an empty list, even though the resource exists.

[image: Powershell]

We have also created a different naming convention and used the ARM Api call to test this and we got the same outcome. See the command below:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***-nodepool-prd-devtest/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets?api-version=2020-12-01 -Method GET -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'

Output:

value
-----
{}
```

We have tried to add another VMSS to the same resource group as a test and noticed that made the other one pop up.
[image: Creation of another vmss resolves the issue]

It looks to me as if it is a caching issue but I can't figure out how to resolve it. Any ideas?

Things to keep in mind:

- using the same CLI version as Cloud Shell (2.23.0)
- running the command from the pipeline returns an empty list
- a team member is able to get the resource from their own machine

Answer (score 0):

I saw the similar issue when a specific subscription wasn't show up in a list of output.
We used below ps commands to resolve the issue:

```
Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave
Disconnect-AzureRmAccount
```

As you use the Az module, please try these:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave
Disconnect-AzAccount
```

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6289

PS: it seems you need to edit the title to the "Azure **PS** command returns empty list"

Comment: Thanks for your input on this. I have tried the solution that you mentioned above but no joy. 
We are still experiencing this on local and also when running an inline script query in the pipeline.