# az vmss list command returns empty value

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have two resource groups in Azure, each contains one VMSS (Virtual Machine Scale Sets) and the resources are visible in Azure Portal. The problem is, the following commands return empty output:

```
az resource list --subscription MySubscription -g vmss-rg
az vmss list --subscription MySubscription -g vmss-rg
az vmss list
```

However, running `az resource list` with different resource groups which doesn't have VMSS works fine. I also tested it with different Azure account and subscription, it also worked.

Comment: We have run the above cmdlets in our subscription, those are working fine & we were able to get the list of VMSS that were present under the subscription. Alternatively could please try the below  cmdlet to pull the list of VMSS present under the subscription or in resource group. 

     ``az resource list --resource-type  "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets" -g '<rgName>' ``(OR)``az resource list --resource-type  "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets"``

Comment: Do let us know if face any issue while running the above cmdlets

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT the result is the same: empty list.

Comment: are you trying to run these cmdlets from the local machine through PowerShell or from the cloud shell in the portal . if you are running from the local PowerShell have you installed az modules ?

Comment: I have Azure CLI installed on my local machine, and I user GitBash and/or PowerShell to invoke azure cli commands. I don't use "Azure Az PowerShell module". Btw, I tried the same commands in the Cloud Shell in the portal and it worked. Actually it was working on the local machine as well about a month ago.

Comment: Almost a week after creation of the VMSS resources, now it shows properly.
PS: I didn't update/upgrade any module, it just worked after a week.

Answer (score 1):

We have tested the same command in our local as suggested by @[***VenkateshDodda-MT***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15968720/venkateshdodda-mt) and it works fine. Posting it as an answer to help other community members for the similar issue so that they can find and  fix their problem.

To achieve the above requirement we need to [***`install the az powershell module`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-7.3.0) in our local .

Post that run the command in powershell to get the `vmss` list under our subscription or resource groups:-

```
az resource list --resource-type  "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets"
```

***OUTPUT:-***

[image]

To get the VMSS list under particular resource group run the below cmd:

```
az resource list --resource-type  "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets" -g '<rgName>'
```

***OUTPUT:-***
[image]

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD:Azure PS command returns empty list***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67702943/azure-ps-command-returns-empty-list) as suggested by @[***Olga Osinskaya - MSFT***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8882142/olga-osinskaya-msft)